# NodeJs note app delete function is not working?

Tags: arrays, node.js

I am building a Nodejs Note app and I am very new at this, so here the delete function doesn't work it, deletes everything from the array and I want to delete only title
There are two file app.js and note.js.

Here's the content of app.js file

```
if (command === "add") {
    var note = notes.addNote(argv.title, argv.body);
    if (note) {
        console.log("Note created");
        console.log("__");
        console.log(`Title: ${note.title}`);
        console.log(`Body: ${note.body}`);
    } else {
        console.log("The title has already exist")
    }
} else if (command === "delete") {
    var noteRemoved = notes.delNote(argv.title)
    var message = noteRemoved ? "Note has been removed" : "Note not found";
    console.log(message)
}
```

Here's the note.js content

```
var fetchNotes = function () {
    try {
        var noteString = fs.readFileSync("notes-data.json")
        return JSON.parse(noteString);
    } catch (e) {
        return [];
    }
};

var saveNotes = function (notes) {
    fs.writeFileSync("notes-data.json", JSON.stringify(notes));
};

var addNote = function (title, body) {
    var notes = fetchNotes();
    var note = {
        title,
        body
    };

    var duplicateNotes = notes.filter(function (note) {
        return note.title === title;

    });

    if (duplicateNotes.length === 0) {
        notes.push(note);
        saveNotes(notes);
        return note;
    };
}

var delNote = function (title) {
    var notes = fetchNotes();
    var filteredNotes = notes.filter(function (note) {
        note.title !== title;
    });
    saveNotes(filteredNotes);
    return notes.length !== filteredNotes.length
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss return statement in delNote filter function

```
var filteredNotes = notes.filter(function (note) {
    return note.title !== title;
});
```

or we can use es6 syntax:

```
const filteredNotes = notes.filter(note => note.title !== title);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `return note.title !== title;` in delNote function.